# Can I simply convert an integral into an expectation by "declaring" that the variable is a random variable?

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables, expected-value, average

I know that

$\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx = (b-a)\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\frac{1}{b-a}dx = (b-a)E[g(X)]$

where $X$ has a $Uniform(a,b)$ distribution.

However, **I don't understand how the second step turns the integral into an expected value**.  It's as if I can simply "declare" that $X$ is a random variable.  Somehow, it seems like I'm hand-waving some magic into the equation, and I wonder if I am missing a step.

Comment: Shouldn't $X$ have a $\mathrm{Uniform}(a,b)$ distribution?

Comment: If $X\sim\mathrm{Unif}(a,b)$, notice that $\Bbb E[g(X)]:=\int_a^b g(x)P(X=x)~\mathrm dx=\int_a^b g(x)\frac 1{b-a}~\mathrm dx$ which is why the transformation to expectation works.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Yes, thanks for noticing that! I fixed it.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Ah, OK - I should have started with the definition of expectation, then convert it into the definite integral that I began with. Thank you. In your definition of expectation, I think that the integrand should be $g(x)f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is the probability density function. Would you like to write this as a solution? I'll mark it as solved afterward.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for noticing that. Indeed, I meant pdf because $P(X=x)$ is just $0$ for a continuous rv $X$. Ok, I'll write an answer.

Comment: "It's as if I can simply "declare" that  is a random variable." Yup - you can! You can define a random variable however you like as long as it meets the definition of random variable.  We just say "Define $X$ to be the variable uniform on $(a,b)$." Then you note that $X$ has density function $\rho(x) = 1/(b-a)$ and apply the definition of expectation of a continuous random variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this works because it follows from the definition of expectation of a continuous random variable.

Consider a continuous random variable $X$ defined on some interval $I$ with some distribution with pdf $f_X(x)$. Then,

$$\Bbb E[g(X)]:=\int_I g(x)f_X(x)~\mathrm dx$$

The question here corresponds to $X\sim\mathrm{Unif}(a,b)$ for which $f_X(x)=\frac 1{b-a}$ for $x\in [a,b]$ and $0$ otherwise, so we have,

$$\Bbb E[X]:=\int_a^b g(x)\frac 1{b-a}~\mathrm dx\implies (b-a)\Bbb E[X]=\int_a^b g(x)~\mathrm dx$$